Spring Boot RestClient does not work when sending an object
I tried sending a POST request using Spring Boot 3 Http RestClient. The request fails when sending and object and passes when sending a string.
Works with string code:
    private final String roleBody = """
    {"ApplicationID":"XXXX","RolesValues":["ROLE"],"retainPreviousRoles":"true"}
    """;

        ResponseEntity<ApiResponse> result = restClient
            .post()
            .uri("dev/v1/app-roles")
            .accept(APPLICATION_JSON)
            .contentType(APPLICATION_JSON)
            .body(addAppRole)
            .body(roleBody)
            .retrieve()
            .toEntity(ApiResponse.class);

Debug output from turning on http client logging:
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/5.2.3 (Java/17.0.11)
"POST /dev/v1/app-roles HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
"Content-Type: application/json[\r][\n]"
"Accept: application/json[\r][\n]"
"Accept-Encoding: gzip, x-gzip, deflate[\r][\n]"
"Content-Length: 128[\r][\n]"
"Host: appregapi.bpglobal.com[\r][\n]"
"Connection: keep-alive[\r][\n]"
"User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/5.2.3 (Java/17.0.11)[\r][\n]"
"[\r][\n]"
"{"ApplicationID":"XXXX","RolesValues":["ROLE"],"retainPreviousRoles":"true"}[\n]"
"HTTP/1.1 200 OK[\r][\n]"
"Transfer-Encoding: chunked[\r][\n]"
"Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8[\r][\n]"
"Content-Encoding: gzip[\r][\n]"
"Vary: Accept-Encoding[\r][\n]"
"Date: Sat, 08 Jun 2024 20:22:09 GMT[\r][\n]"
"[\r][\n]"
"44[\r][\n]"

Fails when an object code:
        AddAppRole addAppRole = AddAppRole.builder()
            .applicationId("XXXX")
            .rolesValues(List.of("ROLE"))
            .retainPreviousRoles("true")
            .build();

        ResponseEntity<ApiResponse> result = restClient
            .post()
            .uri("dev/v1/app-roles")
            .accept(APPLICATION_JSON)
            .contentType(APPLICATION_JSON)
            .body(addAppRole)
            .retrieve()
            .toEntity(ApiResponse.class);


Debug output from turning on http client logging:
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/5.2.3 (Java/17.0.11)
"POST /dev/v1/app-roles HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
"Content-Type: application/json[\r][\n]"
"Accept: application/json[\r][\n]"
"Accept-Encoding: gzip, x-gzip, deflate[\r][\n]"
"Transfer-Encoding: chunked[\r][\n]"
"Host: appregapi.bpglobal.com[\r][\n]"
"Connection: keep-alive[\r][\n]"
"User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/5.2.3 (Java/17.0.11)[\r][\n]"
"[\r][\n]"
"7f[\r][\n]"
"{"ApplicationID":"XXXX","RolesValues":["ROLE"],"retainPreviousRoles":"true"}[\r][\n]"
"0[\r][\n]"
"[\r][\n]"
"HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden[\r][\n]"
"Transfer-Encoding: chunked[\r][\n]"
"Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8[\r][\n]"
"Date: Sat, 08 Jun 2024 20:23:35 GMT[\r][\n]"
"[\r][\n]"
"46[\r][\n]"
"{[\r][\n]"
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden

There appear differences in the payloads?
Any idea why the second version is adding:
7f \r \n
and
0 \r \n
The different encoding is breaking the request.
Edit:
Here is the AddAppRole class.
    @Builder
    @JsonPropertyOrder(value = {"ApplicationID", "RolesValues", "retainPreviousRoles"})
    public class AddAppRole {
        @JsonProperty("ApplicationID")
        private final String applicationId;

        @JsonProperty("RolesValues")
        private final List<String> rolesValues;

        private final String retainPreviousRoles;
    }

I noticed it was chunked, unsure how to stop it from being chunked with the new client or why this might alter the body.

Do you mind sharing your AddAppRole class ?
The issue appears to stem from the way the body is being serialized and transmitted in the two different approaches. When you directly send a JSON string, it is transmitted as-is, whereas when you send an object, it is serialized by the Spring Boot RestClient. The extra characters you're seeing (7f \r \n and 0 \r \n) indicate chunked transfer encoding, which is a way to send data in chunks and is often used when the content length is unknown beforehand.
To address this, you can try a few approaches:
Ensure Correct Serialization:
Verify that your AddAppRole class is correctly serialized to JSON. Make sure all the fields in AddAppRole match the expected JSON keys exactly. You might need to use Jackson annotations to specify the correct field names if they differ from the class field names.
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
public class AddAppRole {
    @JsonProperty("ApplicationID")
    private String applicationId;

    @JsonProperty("RolesValues")
    private List<String> rolesValues;

    @JsonProperty("retainPreviousRoles")
    private String retainPreviousRoles;
}

If the problem persists, you can manually convert the object to JSON and send it as a string, ensuring the body format remains consistent:
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
String roleBody = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(addAppRole);

ResponseEntity<ApiResponse> result = restClient
    .post()
    .uri("dev/v1/app-roles")
    .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    .body(BodyInserters.fromValue(roleBody))
    .retrieve()
    .toEntity(ApiResponse.class)
    .block();

